# Figure not updated on jupyter notebook (sparkmagic)

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, livy

I am running the following command in a jupyter notebook with [sparkmagic](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic) in order to create a figure.

```py
df.toPandas().boxplot()
```

And in order to show the figure I run in a different cell

```
%matplot plt
```

The first time I run it, it works well.

If I run it again by changing the dataframe (*e.g.* by adding some filter), and run `%matplot plt` one more time, the figure won't change.

I have notice the output of the "boxplot cell" does not change: I have for example:

```
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fecf77d36a0>
```

How can this figure be updated? Is there a way to clear/clean the current figure in order to reset it?